# I Upgraded my parrot linux and start getting these errors

Tags: apt, upgrade, parrotsec

```
Scanning application launchers
Removing duplicate launchers or broken launchers
 [-] Invalid binary pentestexec at launcher /usr/share/applications/dumpzilla.desktop
 [-] Invalid binary xboard at launcher /usr/share/applications/xboard-config.desktop
 [-] Invalid binary xboard at launcher /usr/share/applications/xboard-fen-viewer.desktop
 [-] Invalid binary xboard at launcher /usr/share/applications/xboard-pgn-viewer.desktop
 [-] Invalid binary xboard at launcher /usr/share/applications/xboard-tourney.desktop
 [-] Invalid binary xboard at launcher /usr/share/applications/xboard.desktop
 [-] Invalid binary pentestexec at launcher /usr/share/applications/parrot-dumpzilla.desktop
Launchers are updated
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an error. I had a similar output, and `echo $?` gave me 0. Try running it again. When I ran it again, I didn't get the invalid binary messages.